# How to separate monochromatic objects of different sizes in opencv

Tags: python, java, c#, c++, opencv

I want to separate a noiseless 1-bit (black and white) image with white circles based on the concave part of the outline.
Please refer to the picture below.

This is the white object to separate:

[image: white circle]

The target result is:

[image: goal circle]

Here is my implementation with the watershed algorithm:

[image: implemented circle]

The above result is not what I want.
If the size of the separated objects is similar, my algorithm is fine, but if the size difference is large, a problem occurs as shown in the picture above.
I would like to implement an opencv algorithm that can segment a region like the second picture.

However, the input photo is not necessarily a perfect circle.
It can be oval like the picture below:

[image: white ellipse]

Or it can be squished:

[image: squished shape]   [image: squished shape color]

However, I would like to separate it based on the concave part of the outline anyway.

I think it can be implemented by using the distanceTransform function well, but I'm not sure how to approach it.
Please let me know which way to refer.
Thank you.

Comment: Which programming language do you use with opencv? This would be of interest if someone wants to share a code example with you. Please add the according tag to your question!

Comment: You could search for convexityDefects if your objects are mostly convex.

Comment: @markus The opencv library works similarly in any language, so I didn't specify a specific language.
I want to use opencv in c#(unity), but c++, python, java also don't care.
I'll add it to the tag.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Is the number of "circles" known?

Comment: @marcoromelli No, the number of circles is not provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the minimal openings, you can use a [medial axis](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.medial_axis) based approach.

Pseudo code:

```
compute contours of bitmap
compute medial-axis of bitmap 

for each point on medial-axis:
  get minimal distance d from medial axis algorithm
  for each local minimum of distance d:
    get two points on bitmap contours with minimal distance that are at least d apart from each other
    use these points for deviding line
```

If you need a working implementation in `python`, please let me know. I would use `skimage` lib. For other languages you might have to implement medial-axis on your own. But that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Wow! That's a very clear answer!
I haven't tried it yet, but it's a very attractive way to try it.
When I conducted the thought experiment, I didn't see anything that could be a problem.
I will try it and leave a comment again to let you know the result.
Thank you for suggesting an approach.
If someone comes up with a better algorithm, please leave an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm which should give you a good start.

1. Compute all contours.
2. For each contour compute the convexity defects. If there is no defect the contour is an isolated circle and you can segment it out.
3. After you handled all the isolated circles, you can work out the remaining contours by counting the convexity defects: the number of circles N for each contour is the number of convexity defects divided by 2.
4. Use a clustering algorithm (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html should do well given the shapes you have) and cluster the "white" points using N as the number of clusters to be found.